# Is any way to get cache data from ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Is any way to get cache data from ubuntu?

How can i get L3 cache data from the Ubuntu virtual machine.

The hypervisor is either  XEN hypervisor or VMWARE

Comment: Why would you want that? Isn't it just data that the CPU is/has just used, so you already know what the CPU was sent & returned?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...For cross VM side channel attack, we need to know what is there in the cache after used by victim VM.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

This is why they are referred to as "side channel" attacks, because you can not directly read the values that are in the cache (which would be the security equivalent of writing your passwords on a whiteboard outside your front door) but you can *infer* the presence of data by the *way* that CPU instructions take more or less time depending on what is in the cache.

Reading the CPU cache would be even more insanely dangerous than Spectre and Meltdown already are and would immediately make every protection that VMs have completely worthless from a security perspective.

Absolutely no normal task should need to care about what is in the CPU caches, instead they care about register states and reading/writing memory locations, if a value comes from cache you get a speed-up, but you do not *need* to read the cache in the course of normal use.

I can't even see any *real* reason an administrator or even the OS kernel should *need* to read CPU cache lines. I can see several reasons that from a security perspective that **absolutely no program in the system should have access to cache lines** but only vague convenience reasons why it *should* be allowed.

I would expect that explicit cache line access is not allowed, or at least is denied to anything but the highest processor access state if it is allowed at all. A VM would never be able to run in this state and so any cache access would be denied.

---

I believe that VMs are treated as [Ring 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring), as in they are treated as nothing more than "yet another" application to the host. The host operating system itself runs in Ring 0 with direct hardware access allowed, but applications themselves run with much lower privileges.

Any access from a VM to privileged instructions will be trapped and handled by the VM software rather than actual CPU or system hardware.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer...I accept that i can't read cache data directly..But so many authors  have implemented this cross side channel attack in papers.how is it possible...In the paper,they have not read the information,but they have found that how many cache miss or cache hit have occurred..Is it possible to read such information...

Comment: In the prime + Probe attack, first the attacker is going to fill up their own data in the cache before victim VM access the cache.After victim has accessed ,then the attacker is going to count that cache miss or cache hit while reading same data...

Comment: @G.Sangeetha The spectre attack paper documents the process and explains it better than I could: https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf